# Spherical Triangle with right-angle calculating an angle with one side and one angle

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

[image: Spherical Triangle]
Given the following spherical triangle, is it possible to calculate B
given side b, angle A and angle C = 90 degrees?

If so, which formula is it.

I've tried the sine Rule and cosine rule but I need to know more than one side.

I would use formula:

```
cos A = sin B cos a
```

(from Smart's book on p. 16 and simplifying since C = 90 deg

However side b is my known and I'm trying to find B.
Is it possible to rearrange the formula?

Comment: Which statements of the sin / cosine rules do you know that works for spherical triangles?

Comment: Sine Rule: sin⁡A ̂ /(sin a)=sin⁡B ̂ /(sin b)=sin⁡C ̂ /(sin c)
Cosine rule:
1. cos a = cos b .cos c + sin b sin c cos A ̂
2. cos b = cos c .cos a + sin c sin a cos B ̂
3. cos c = cos a .cos b + sin a sin b cos C ̂

Comment: Refer to [Spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Identities) Napier's rules for right spherical triangles (R9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @[Somos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/438089/somos) for the link; my answer is in Napier's rules:

The full set of rules for the right spherical triangle is (Todhunter,[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/438089/somos) Art.62)

\begin{alignedat}{4}&{\text{(R1)}}&\qquad \cos c&=\cos a\,\cos b,&\qquad \qquad &{\text{(R6)}}&\qquad \tan b&=\cos A\,\tan c,\\&{\text{(R2)}}&\sin a&=\sin A\,\sin c,&&{\text{(R7)}}&\tan a&=\cos B\,\tan c,\\&{\text{(R3)}}&\sin b&=\sin B\,\sin c,&&{\text{(R8)}}&\cos A&=\sin B\,\cos a,\\&{\text{(R4)}}&\tan a&=\tan A\,\sin b,&&{\text{(R9)}}&\cos B&=\sin A\,\cos b,\\&{\text{(R5)}}&\tan b&=\tan B\,\sin a,&&{\text{(R10)}}&\cos c&=\cot A\,\cot B.\end{alignedat}